# Redux, Fetch and where to use .map

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

Consider this scenario:
app loads => fetches json from api => needs to modify json returned

In this case, I'm using moment to make some date modifications and do some grouping that I'll use in the UI. I looked on stack and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545536/react-redux-where-to-process-data-from-api-response-and-dispatching-action-from) but didn't feel like it provided the clarity I am seeking.

1. Where should I use .map to create the new objects that contain the formatted & grouped dates?  Should I manipulate the raw json in the api call or in the redux action before I dispatch? What is the best practice?
2. Is it OK to add properties and mutate the object as I am showing below,
   `service["mStartDate"] = mStartDate` *before* I put the data into my store and treat it as immutable state?

> First Approach - changing raw json in the api call

```
      class TicketRepository extends BaseRepository {
        getDataByID(postData) {
          return this.post('api/lookup', postData)
          .then(result => {
            const groupedData = {}
              return result.map(ticket => {
                  const mStartDate = moment(ticket.startDate)
                  const mEndDate = moment(ticket.endDate)            
                  const serviceLength = mStartDate.diff(mEndDate,'hours')
                  const duration = moment.duration(serviceLength,"hours").humanize()
                  const weekOfYear = mStartDate.format('WW')
                  const dayOfWeek = mStartDate.format("d")

                  if(!groupedData.hasOwnProperty(weekOfYear)){
                    groupedData[weekOfYear] = {}
                  }

                  if (!groupedData[weekOfYear].hasOwnProperty(dayOfWeek)) {
                  groupedData[weekOfYear][dayOfWeek] = []
                  }            

                  service["mStartDate"] = mStartDate
                  service["mEndDate"] = mEndDate
                  service["serviceLength"] = serviceLength
                  service["duration"] = duration
                   groupedData[weekOfYear][dayOfWeek].push(service)
                })                    
          })
        }
      }
```

> 2nd Approach, make a simple api call

```
  class TicketRepository extends BaseRepository {
    getDataByID(postData) {
      return this.post('api/lookup', postData)
    }
  }
```

> Change the json in the action before dispatching

```
    export function getDataByID() {
      return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(dataLookupRequest()) 
        const state = getState()

        const groupedData = {}
        return TicketRepository.getDataByID(userData)
          .then(result => {
            const groupedData = {}
              return result.map(ticket => {
                  const mStartDate = moment(ticket.startDate)
                  const mEndDate = moment(ticket.endDate)            
                  const serviceLength = mStartDate.diff(mEndDate,'hours')
                  const duration = moment.duration(serviceLength,"hours").humanize()
                  const weekOfYear = mStartDate.format('WW')
                  const dayOfWeek = mStartDate.format("d")

                  if(!groupedData.hasOwnProperty(weekOfYear)){
                    groupedData[weekOfYear] = {}
                  }

                  if (!groupedData[weekOfYear].hasOwnProperty(dayOfWeek)) {
                  groupedData[weekOfYear][dayOfWeek] = []
                  }            

                  service["mStartDate"] = mStartDate
                  service["mEndDate"] = mEndDate
                  service["serviceLength"] = serviceLength
                  service["duration"] = duration
                   groupedData[weekOfYear][dayOfWeek].push(service)
                })
                return groupedData   
          })
          .then(groupedData => {
            dispatch(lookupSuccess(groupedData))
          })
          .catch(err => dispatch(dataLookupFailure(err.code, err.message)))
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data manipulation should be handled by your reducer. That is, the returned response data should be passed on to a reducer. This practice is common, because this way if there's a problem with your data, you will always know where to look - reducer. So neither of your approaches is "correct". Actions should just take some input and dispatch an object (no data manipulation).

When you want to manipulate data for 'view' purposes only, consider using [`reselect`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library, which makes it easier to handle "data views" that are composed of the existing data.